# Is there a way to call `fetch().finally()` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

My goal is to do `fetch().then().catch().finally()`. I use

The problem is that the Visual Studio Code's Editor Language for TypeScript does not allow me to do so. I don't install any extension related to TypeScript, it's just there.

Then, I found the interface using the `Go to Definition` feature. The `Promise<T>` interface in `lib.es5.d.ts`. It does not contain `finally()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your compilation target has to be `ES2018` or later.

`Promise.prototype.finally` was introduced [in ES2018](https://flaviocopes.com/es2018/#promiseprototypefinally).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/AoJw9gtglgzgpgOhHGYA2A3OAKALAJgEoEAXACzgDttiBjAQxNrJoQDMpL600BPGoA)